# MS SQL Import Export Wizard Truncating Sub-Seconds even when using DateTime2(4) field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have been having some challenges preserving precision on insertion of a date using the Import/Export Wizard and losing the precision of my date time field. The sub-seconds times are always being lost on the second datetime field.

I am using MS SQL Server 2017. What am I missing / doing wrong to get the Import to work properly?
Ideally I want to create a DTS process to automate this but right now just trying to get the basic import working reliably.

My Raw data looks like this:

```
  2020-12-29 14:59:59,036418016717,2020-12-29 15:00:00.0628
  2020-12-29 15:00:00,000000004249,2020-12-29 15:00:00.0661
  2020-12-29 15:00:00,000000005472,2020-12-29 15:00:00.1448
  2020-12-29 15:00:00,000000001344,2020-12-29 15:00:00.1449
```

My Insert Table for these fields Looks like this:

```
([INCDATETIME] datetime NOT NULL, 
 [SEQNO] bigint,
 [LOGDATETIME] datetime2(4) NOT NULL
```

The first date imports just fine being a `date[DT_DATE]` using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. For the second field I have tried both `date[DT_Date], string(24),` and the other Date Time formats available.. I have also tried defining it as a string in the table and then turn it back into a datetime as a calculated field but it is very inefficient to do so for what I need.

The best case out of all of them is my second date is always imported as "2020-12-29 15:00:00.0000" zeroing out the sub-seconds which I absolutely need for my purpose as I need to compare several fields like it.

I am pretty sure I need to use a DateTime2 as a destination field and even in this little test script it comes out correctly. So why is it not working with the Wizard?

```
DECLARE @mydate date = CONVERT(date,@mytime);
DECLARE @mydatetime2 datetime2(4) = CONVERT(datetime2,@mytime);


SELECT @mytime as 'String', 
       @mydate as 'Date', 
       @mydatetime2 AS 'Datetime2'

String                   Date       Datetime2
------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------
2020-12-29 15:00:00.9494 2020-12-29 2020-12-29 15:00:00.9494
```

Comment: Sounds like the wizard's incorrectly using `smalldatetime` if it's truncating fractional seconds. Have you tried using `bulk insert` with a format file, or `bcp.exe` with a format file?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning As right now trying to get quick and easy then once final come back to those as haven't tried using a format file yet (haven't done that before). The .DTSX file the export wizard is creating says the "dataType="i8" for this field.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Once I got permissions I was able to create  Bulk XML Insert File and that imported it correctly.. still would love to get the wizard working as I'm going to need to  have to create user instructions for the process.. and they like wizards.